# JavaScript: Increment and Decrement Function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am practicing my JavaScript Skills, I have been mastering a simple increment counter function which I seem to have gotten right, so today I wanted to take that script to the next level and decrement the value too,

Here is my issue, when I click **add number**, then I proceed to click **minus number**, the first click still adds one value **before** it is counting down, what am I missing to avoid this from happening?

My code is below:

```js
const output = document.getElementById('counter');
const addBtn = document.getElementById('btn-add');
const minusBtn = document.getElementById('btn-minus');
let number = 0;

function increment() {
  output.innerHTML = number++;
}

function decrement() {
  output.innerHTML = number--;
}

addBtn.addEventListener('click', increment);
minusBtn.addEventListener('click', decrement);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Increment and Decrement Numbers</h1>
  <div class="output">
    <div>
      <p>Your total count is: <span id="counter"></span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button id="btn-add">+</button>
      <button id="btn-minus">-</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is, because you are using a postincrement and postdecrement operator ... Use preincrement and decrement instead.

Comment: ```number++``` returns the value before the increment.

Comment: From MDN: The increment (++) operator increments (adds one to) its operand and returns the value before or after the increment, depending on where the operator is placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using `number++` to increment the `number` variable, the statement returns the value before incrementation. You want to use `++number` instead of `number++` if you want to get the number after the incrementation.

Likewise for `--`, naturally.

Comment: _"when using ++ to increment a number, the statement returns the value before incrementation"_ - There are two version of the `++` operator, hence the sentence, in its current form, is only partially true.

Comment: Thanks so much, I understand that now, i was watching some lectures about that last time but didnt make as much sense, after your advice and implementing your solution, i totally grasp it now thank you

Comment: @Andreas Absolutely true, edited for clarity.